# my gesture recognizer is working backwards in swift

Tags: swift

greetings Im very new to Swift (only 1 month)

I have added a gesture recognizer to a UIbutton which performs a segue to a new view controller

I want it not work on double or triple click

right now it works on a single click but does nothing on a double click.

so in reality its working in reverse

thanks in advance for any help

here is my code

}

```
@IBOutlet weak var setScreenButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


   let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(setter: setScreenButton))
   tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
   setScreenButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@IBAction func setScreenButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSeg", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: That's because you are adding the gesture to a wrong object.  Your button is doing its job as a push button, which is triggered when one taps it.

Comment: most grateful El Tomato, I see that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will make your UIButton recognize the double-tap. I removed the IBAction because it is what recognizes the single tap as @ElTomato mentioned.

You could simply use an image and attach the gesture recognizer to it instead and make sure the user interaction is enabled on the image to recognize the taps.

```
@IBOutlet weak var screenButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(setScreenButton))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    screenButton.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

@objc func setScreenButton(){
    print("tapped")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSeg", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now. BUT it is still triggering the Segue on a single click. double click now works ... but also single. could you advise please ?

Comment: @Geno did you remove IBAction?

Comment: yes I did .. the code is exactly as you said. It works fine now but any amount of clicks.

Comment: I tested it and works fine for me. Did you maybe from the main storyboard drag from the button to perform the segue connection?

Comment: comment out the performSegue and see if it prints "tapped" when clicked once

Comment: Thanks so much for your help .. Ive figured it out .... The Segue was on the UIButton so it was overriding the Tap Gesture. Now the Segue is on the view controller and its perfect ....

Comment: No problem Geon :)